# Программа падает по нажатию кнопки

Tags: java, android

Программа должна по нажатию кнопки увеличивать значение TextView, но при нажатии падает с ошибкой(

Текст ошибки из Logcat:

```
03-10 17:30:48.025 23561-23561/com.example.android.countcounter E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                  Process: com.example.android.countcounter, PID: 23561
                                                                                  java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick
                                                                                      at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:293)
                                                                                      at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4819)
                                                                                      at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:20152)
                                                                                      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:815)
                                                                                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:104)
                                                                                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5562)
                                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:968)
                                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:763)
                                                                                   Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
                                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                                      at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:288)
                                                                                      at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4819) 
                                                                                      at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:20152) 
                                                                                      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:815) 
                                                                                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:104) 
                                                                                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194) 
                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5562) 
                                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
                                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:968) 
                                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:763) 
                                                                                   Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x1
                                                                                      at android.content.res.Resources.getText(Resources.java:312)
                                                                                      at android.content.res.MiuiResources.getText(MiuiResources.java:124)
                                                                                      at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:4157)
                                                                                      at com.example.android.countcounter.MainActivity.plusScore(MainActivity.java:27)
                                                                                      at com.example.android.countcounter.MainActivity.a_plus_one(MainActivity.java:19)
                                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
                                                                                      at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:288) 
                                                                                      at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4819) 
                                                                                      at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:20152) 
                                                                                      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:815) 
                                                                                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:104) 
                                                                                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194) 
                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5562) 
                                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
                                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:968) 
                                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:763)
```

XML описание кнопки:

```
 <Button
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="+1"
                android:background="#FF9800"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:textSize="30sp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
                android:onClick="a_plus_one"/>
```

MainActivity:

```
package com.example.android.countcounter;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }



    public void a_plus_one(View v) {
        plusScore("a_team_score", 1);
    }

    private void plusScore(String teamId, int score) {
        int ResID = getResources().getIdentifier(teamId, "id", getPackageName());
        TextView TeamScore = (TextView) findViewById(ResID);
        int tmp = Integer.parseInt(TeamScore.getText().toString());
        tmp += score;
        TeamScore.setText(tmp);
    }

}
```

Я только начинаю изучать андроид и пока испытываю трудности с расшифровкой ошибок по логу( Буду рад помощи

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
TeamScore.setText(tmp);
```

Замените на

```
TeamScore.setText(String.valueOf(tmp));
```

`TextView` имеет метод [setText(int)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setText(int)), который принимает id ресурса, найти ресурс не может и падает.

---

PS

1) Не называйте переменные с большой буквы `TextView TeamScore`, java конвенция четко регламентирует этот момент

2) Не вешайте слушатель в `xml` `android:onClick=`, не знаю когда это может быть удобней, чем `setOnClickListener()`

3) Не нужно каждый раз, при клике, вызывать `findViewById`, нужно объявить TextView полем класса и вызвать `findViewById` один раз в `onCreate()`

4) Не понял зачем вам

```
 int ResID = getResources().getIdentifier(teamId, "id", getPackageName());
 TextView TeamScore = (TextView) findViewById(ResID);
```

думаю будет достаточно

```
TextView TeamScore = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.a_team_score);
```

Comment: Просто там в идеале будет 2 TextView и хочу 1-й функцией к обоим обращаться